# Ionic native push registration format changed?

Tags: ionic-framework, push-notification, ionic3, apple-push-notifications, ionic-native

I am not sure why but it seems that the interface for push registration changed?

My app follows the logic from

https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/push/

with

```
pushObject.on('registration').subscribe((registration: any) => console.log('Device registered', registration));
```

where `registration` used to be of below type

```
export interface PushDevice{
    registrationId: string;
    registrationType: string;
}
```

but now I am getting

```
{"registrationId":"{length=32,bytes=0x459ca46ab66f4fe790220809215176d6...21b3436d13e78c64}","registrationType":"APNS"}
```

`registrationID` used to be a string, but now is a dictionary. How shall I handle this ID now? I have to convert it to a push token somehow... What changed? I looked into the phone gap plugin code but I can not find it... 
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/src/ios/PushPlugin.m

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found a lead. Seems this changed with the release of iOS 13.

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/117545

The Cordova push plugin has to be updated to v2.3.0 (I have not tested this yet), but my current version is failing because v2.2.3 is accessing the `registrationId` through a wrong method.

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/issues/2832
https://github.com/proreact/phonegap-plugin-push/commit/486c8f206536995c80101487b0fed1502edd5754

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue in my ionic 1 app. Had to upgrade version of push plugin to 2.3.0 from 2.2.3. Moreover i also upgraded cordova-support-google-services to 1.3.2 to make it work. Although it was related to android but still had to do it. This plugin (phonegap-plugin-multidex) should have a version greater than or equal to 1.0.0
The plugins through which push notifications work fine for me are as follows:

phonegap-plugin-multidex 1.0.0 "Multidex"

phonegap-plugin-push 2.3.0 "PushPlugin"

cordova-support-google-services 1.3.2 "cordova-support-google-services"

Hoepfully this helps